# Next.js: Navigate to other page without re-render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

in my app I have two pages:

```
/pages
  index.js
  [page].js
```

Both files share the same content. I do that to handle incoming requests on "/" and other urls, let's say "/foo" and "/bar".

When I navigate via Link between "/foo" and "/bar" I use the router flag shallow=true, which causes no re-render. But when I navigate to the index page the complete content is re-rendering.
Is it possible to prevent that when navigating to other pages? Or is that the completely wrong approach and there is a possibility to handle all incoming requests in just one file?

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution by using catch-all routes. In my example it would be:

```
/pages/[[...page]].js
```